# Localhost httpd.conf reset Yosemite

Tags: localhost, httpd.conf

I don't know if I uncomment too many lines from httpd.conf file. (Is it even possible?)
Is it possible to get original file from somewhere?

Im trying to do this:
virtual.abc.com should point to folder
/Users/me/Sites

I get already php and mysql running and virtual.abc.com to point same folder as localhost

Comment: Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)

Comment: headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)

Comment: unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)

Comment: Do I have some problem with the modules that are loaded?